# How to prevent that users can create a object with the same value in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I've spend some time to search and try to find a rule that I can use in firebase to prevent that the users can create an object with the same value.

This is my database looks:

```
- MyObject
      -KlhEnx432IGfS1QKl_Yaddclose
          timestamp: 1496481480774
          uid: false
          code: "aa"
          date: "2018-06-03T02:00:00Z"
```

That I want to do is put a rule that any user can create another object with the code: aa

This is my rules in firebase console:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "MyObject": {
      ".indexOn": "code"
      }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can do it by using Functions https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Comment: What do you mean by **create another object with the code: aa**

Comment: I mean that I don't want to create another object that have the atribute code:aa